# Having too many methods unused without being commented out could decrease RAM efficiency as well?

Tags: java, android, ram, memory-consumption

I was wondering if having too many methods (performing heavy tasks) unused without being commented out could decrease RAM efficiency as well?

Of course it will affect the APK size. The reason I am asking is because my app is already being killed by the OS, so I don't need to make it more "heavier".

I just want to be sure that if a method is never called, even though it's not commented out, it will not affect RAM-consumption.

Edit:

Basically at the moment I have two apps (two projects), one for a root version and one for a rootless version, in which I have classes with the same name but with different methods.
Since I not capable to unify the two projects by using flavors (please check here: [One of source directories is not marked as source set when using different flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388315/one-of-source-directories-is-not-marked-as-source-set-when-using-different-flavo)) I thought about simply making all the methods in one single class.

For instance:

In project #1 `com.example.root.MyClass` has `method1()` and `method2()` that are needed for the root version of my app.

In project #2 `com.example.rootless.MyClass` has `method3()` and `method4()` that are needed for the rootless version of my app.

In the unified project I would just have `com.example.unified.MyClass` with `method1()`, `method2()`, `method3()`, `method4()`.

What I want to do now is basically let the user choose in the MainActivity which version wants to use and after that would be called activities, layouts, services and methods only for the version chosen.

Comment: @Eldinur I don't know about Android specifically, but this is untrue for Java in general. If you write methods they will get compiled and they will get included it in the `.class` file, and thus the methods will get loaded if the class gets loaded.

Comment: @Eldinur The removal of unused code is done by ProGuard, no? Not the compiler.

Comment: Ermm .... why does your app contain lots of code that is never called?  How much code are you actually talking about?

Comment: @StephenC because I am trying to unify two projects. Probably like 10 more methods per class. I've updated the question to make you understand the issue.

Comment: Roughly how many methods in total?  Roughly how many lines of code that won't be called?  Hundreds?  Thousands?

Comment: Not more than a hundred, yes.